# PHP class design - including a whole class just for a constant?

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm a relative newb and looking for some advice on PHP class design.

If I have a class (lets call it class A) and it performs a database query that requires a constant defined in class B. It looks as though I have three options:

1) Include/require/use the whole class B. Pro: Follows a purer OO approach Con:The whole class has to be loaded just to get access to a constant.

2) Define a separate constants class. Pro:Centralised constant definitions. Con:Goes against encapsulation, more IO processing time with additional includes.

3) Duplicate the class B constant within class A. Pro:Seems to be the best option in terms of processing Con:Duplicate definitions within the OO model.

I'd appreciate any input on this..

Comment: 4) Should that constant be inside of class `B` in the first place?

Comment: I think there are many sides to this coin. Personally I think constants belong only to their associated object. With the exception of pathing constants. Or you could create a generic class that acts as a template for other classes with a set of default methods/variables to allow easier creation of classes etc. there are many options with this that has to many pros/cons to definitely say this or that

Comment: I agree ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs which is why option 1 sits more comfortably with me but seems the worst option in terms of performance.

Comment: Is your program doing so little else or needs that constant so many times that you're already worrying about performance?

Comment: Federico, I guess I like asking the question rather than just go with anything that works. The reality is I'm adding a function (that is rarely used) to an existing class which requires a constant from another relatively large class. It just seems like a sledgehammer approach to include the whole other class which affects every call to it, just for a constant. So I was asking the bigger question.

Comment: Then I stand by my previous comment: probably that constant is in the wrong place. But without knowing much else about your code, it's a bit difficult to give a conclusive suggestion. (PS: next time please put an `@` before the username you're responding to, so that user will be notified of your answer. I just happened to revisit the page and saw your comment, otherwise I wouldn't have known)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for the tip on the username, I didn't want to muddy the question by including specifics as it would probably lead to more questions and clarification than the theory I proposed. But I do get your point.

Comment: Unless you actually write drivers and stuff (and even in such case only after thorough profiling) you can neglect "terms of processing". This is simply not the place you should be looking for optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Your proposition are good I think better aproach is create class just with your constant you need and extend this class when you need on other class

class constant = prop constants

class A extend constant (class)

Comment: @JAMMac from the Object-Oriented Design point of view this is wrong. You should prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Ask yourself "is class **A** actually a **subtype** of class **Constant**". If the answer is no, you should not use inheritance.